# Cannot access a website from Ubuntu desktop,while the website is live

Tags: ssh, ssl

I has a website hosted on CentOS VPS. That website has a self signed certificate.

Now,I migrated that site to another host. I generated keys for using sftp and ssh in old hosting.

The problem is that now I am unable to access the site from ubuntu. Whereas it is accessible from other computers.

I tried various browsers (firefox, google-chrome, chromium) but I cant open the site. Deleting the cache also didn't change things.

Any clue?

This is what happens in chromium:

[image]

**UPDATE:** 
I ran `ssh-keygen -R hostname` that didn't help. Finally I deleted known_hosts file as well, still not working.

Uninstalling and re-installing the browser didn't solve the issue.

Logging out as guest user also didn't open the page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unable to access the site"? What happens when you try to access it? What are the exact error messages in your browser? Are there any messages in the server logs when you try to access the site?

Comment: Updated question. That's what happens. But the site is working fine on others systems and mobile.

Comment: Looks like a name resolution problem. Can you access other sites from this machine? Can do successfully fetch DNS information on the command line (for example with `host` or `dig`)? When you `dig` the DNS info for your site, does it answer with the correct IP address (of the new host)? Maybe this machine gets its DNS info from a name server that hasn't been notified of the move yet, or the old IP (or some other IP, like of a development machine) has been "hard coded" in `/etc/hosts`, or something to that effect.

Comment: Yes, I am able to access other websites. When I `dig hostname` it's showing old hosting information!

Comment: Oh it means I need to wait for the DNS information to propagate. Why don't you leave an answer.

Comment: If the move has been less than 24 hours (rule of thumb) ago, that is probably the case. I posted an answer to that effect below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this machine is using another name server than other machines, and this name server doesn't list the correct (new) IP address for your domain. If you change a DNS record, it at first is only changed in the name server you changed it at. So if a machine uses another name server, it still gets told that your site is at the old IP. But name servers "talk to each other" on a regular basis and update their records accordingly. This of course takes some time. As a rule of thumb, after 24 hours most name servers should "know" about a change. Sometimes it goes faster, sometimes it takes more time.

If after about 24 hours your browser still gets directed to the wrong (old) IP, you'd want to take a closer look at your network settings and/or talk to your internet provider.

Answer (score 1):

[Henning](https://askubuntu.com/users/48867/henning-kockerbeck) already answered the question very well. Further, linux also caches the DNS nameservers for domains that are visited. This cache can be flushed using nscd.

First `sudo apt-get install nscd` if you don't have it installed. Then flush the DNS cache using `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart`

This did not solve my problem, but it confirmed that DNS is not resolved from ISP end.

Comment: thanks a lot Chirag. I wasn't able to access google for quite a while. It solved the problem :)